# Parse ImageMagick histogram color string and populate associative array

Tags: php, regex, imagemagick, histogram, text-parsing

I have ImageMagick histogram color info in string. I want to parse the string using PHP's `preg_match()` function, but I do not have enough knowledge about regular expressions.

```
$str = "588: ( 99, 75, 52) #634B34 srgb(99,75,52)";
preg_match('/(?P<colors>\d+\:)/', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Expected output

```
Array
(
    [colors] => 588,
    [red] => 99,
    [green] => 75,
    [blue] => 52
)
```

How do I get the desired output, or is there another way to get colors and density?

Comment: from where you're trying to get rgb values?

Comment: You started already the right way, just continue matching: ...`\s*\(\s*(?P<red>\d+),\s*(?P<green>\d+)`... [test here](http://regex101.com/r/iR5eM1/1)

Comment: You mean this http://regex101.com/r/oH7yE3/2 ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj yes, it according requirement thanks, can we target before color code (`#634B34`) values `588: ( 99, 75, 52)` because `srgb(....)` not fixed may be color name comes here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this,

```
(?P<colors>\d+):\s*\(\s*(?P<red>\d+),\s*(?P<green>\d+),\s*(?P<blue>\d+)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/oH7yE3/3)

Answer (score 1):

`sscanf()` is an awesome function to call upon for this task because:

1. It is simply and more concise than regex,
2. It allow optional whitespace before captured numbers to be ignored,
3. The capture numbers are cast as integers instead of strings like `preg_` functions return, and
4. There is no reference variable to declare; the array of captured values is returned by the function.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/TokC9))

```
$str = "588: ( 99, 75, 52) #634B34 srgb(99,75,52)";

[
    $result['colors'],
    $result['red'],
    $result['green'],
    $result['blue']
] = sscanf($str, '%d: (%d,%d,%d)');
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'colors' => 588,
  'red' => 99,
  'green' => 75,
  'blue' => 52,
)
```

---

Or you can declare the elements inside the function itself for the same result. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/O9fih)

```
sscanf(
    $str,
    '%d: (%d,%d,%d)',
    $result['colors'],
    $result['red'],
    $result['green'],
    $result['blue']
);
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use this regex for getting the values in srgb:

```
$str = "588: ( 99, 75, 52) #634B34 srgb(99,75,52)";
preg_match_all("/srgb\s*\(\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*\)/i", $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

so if you have your string always like this:

```
substr($str, 0,3);
```

will be 588

Comment: first digits length not fixed, and i tried your code nothing output https://eval.in/205296

Comment: you were printing (matches) not ($matches)! change it to $matches